# Different CSS sheet depending on screen size, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I have created 2 different versions of my website, one for laptop screen size and one for mobile screen size (tablet screen size, on the way). So, I was wondering if you could tell me how am I supposed to use javascript (because I have a feeling that it could be done through javascript) in order to have as a main webpage file the one that is supposed to be for laptops and in case the user opens my website through their mobile, the file that will open will be the one for mobile size screens. I hope you get my question.

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: I read something about @media but still trying to figure things out.
PS2: If you need me to post any code, let me know which part you might need and I will gladly post it.

Comment: check this - https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: Thanks @TiagoMartinho. Now, can you tell me where exaclty should I put the media? In my mobile screen .html or in my laptop screen .html files? Should I put media { } and inside the brackets the css style?

Comment: If you have CSS apart from HTML, which is advisable, you should put the media queries in that CSS file.

Comment: check this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ

Comment: To be honest, I don't have them seperately but it is easily managable to do so. I'll give it a go! Thanks

Comment: A youtube video! I love it. I'm gonna check it! Thanks a lot for your help @TiagoMartinho.

Comment: Separating content from style be useful for the one reason: code duplication. If two elements share the same style, you shouldn't be writing the style twice: you should define it once, and then reuse it. Writing it twice leads to maintenance problems which are too obvious to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **media queries** to import different CSS files, depending on screen size.
This will work without javascript and would be the prefered approach in my opinion.

Your site could have the following code in a  tag in the header:

`/* Everything 1000px and lower */
@import url("./mobile.css") only screen and (max-width: 1000px);`

This will load another stylesheet if the media query is satisfied.

You can read more about media queries here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

Use **media queries** in your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

Examples and more, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: Thanks @Damian. I already knew about that but in my case it's not that simple as a background color. I need something that can pull a different .html file if the user opens my website through mobile or laptop screen

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to responsive, avoid as much as you can javascript, you can do it with css media queries, you can learn more about it here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
or you can go for the framework approach, bootstrap for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use bootstrap, you can easily manage you requirement quickly.
Please refer following link to get idea -
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/

Comment: Thanks @YMA. I'll check it out to see if it's helpful

Comment: First of all you have to learn bootstrap grid system.Please follow this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to handle css on you web page

// For Ipad Portrait and Landscape

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
```

// For iPhone and smaller devices

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

also to handle javascript you need to use device width in jquery

```
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
   alert('Less than 767');
}
else {
   alert('More than 767');
}
```